# Type hint issue when base class is parameterized on a value type and has methods that return that type

Tags: python, python-typing

This a toy example to illustrate the issue:

```py
from typing import Type
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
import json

@dataclass
class ValueType1:
    x: int
    y: int

@dataclass
class ValueType2:
    x: int
    z: str

class FooBase:
    def __init__(self, value_cls: Type[ValueType1|ValueType2], name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.value_cls = value_cls
    def save(self, value: ValueType1|ValueType2):
        with open(self.name+'.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(asdict(value), f)
    def load(self) -> ValueType1|ValueType2:
        with open(self.name+'.json', 'r') as f:
            return self.value_cls(**json.load(f))
    
class Foo1(FooBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(value_cls=ValueType1, name='1')
class Foo2(FooBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(value_cls=ValueType2, name='2')

foo1 = Foo1()
foo2 = Foo2()
foo1.save(ValueType1(x=10, y=20))
foo2.save(ValueType2(x=10, z='a'))
res1 = foo1.load()
res2 = foo2.load()
print(res1.y)
print(res2.z)
```

This works fine and prints 20 and 'a' as expected but typing errors are shown at `res1.y` and `res2.z` of this sort (only `res1.y` errors shown):

```
Type of "y" is unknownPylancereportUnknownMemberType
Type of "y" is partially unknown
  Type of "y" is "int | Unknown"PylancereportUnknownMemberType
Argument type is partially unknown
  Argument corresponds to parameter "values" in function "print"
  Argument type is "int | Unknown"PylancereportUnknownArgumentType
Cannot access member "y" for type "ValueType2"
  Member "y" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
(variable) y: int | Unknown
```

I'm wondering if there is some type hinting magic that can resolve this and make it clear that `res1` is of type `ValueType1`. Thanks!

Comment: Since you basically override stuff in a very similar fashion in all subclasses, [generic](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=dc50731f223fce3dc6cb0aa8dba0d440) approach might fit better (gist mine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this:

```py
from typing import Callable

class Foo1(FooBase):
    load: Callable[[], ValueType1]
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(value_cls=ValueType1, name='1')

class Foo2(FooBase):
    load: Callable[[], ValueType2]
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(value_cls=ValueType2, name='2')
```

Some editors will now pick `load()` up as a attribute and not a function and color it wrong though. But type hints will work properly

Comment: Thanks! That removed the error from `res1.y` and `res2.z` but now I get an error at the newly added lines: `Method "load" overrides class "FooBase" in an incompatible manner.   Positional parameter count mismatch; base method has 1, but override has 0`

Comment: Ok. replacing `load: Callable[[], ValueType1]` with `load: Callable[..., ValueType1]` (and the other one) removed all the errors.

Comment: yea sorry about that. The ... version was what my editor suggested to me and I didn't edit in time.